# Function to count the frequency of each word in a string using two parallel arrays

Tags: c++

I am trying to count the frequency of each word in a given string using two arrays and WITHOUT using Maps or Vectors.

One array to store the words and the other to count the frequency of each word I believe.

I have been teaching myself C++ in my off time and this problem has given me more trouble than I'd like to admit and I've been stuck on it. Maps and Vectors are easier to me, but the problem says specifically not to use them.

This is the code that I used Maps to create pairs but now I need two strings to do the same thing basically.

```
void wordCounter(string str, string wordsArray[], int countArray[]){
map<string, int> passage; 
string word = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
  if (str[i] == ' '){
    if(passage.find(word) == passage.end()){
        passage.insert(make_pair(word, 1));
        word = "";
    }else{
      passage[word]++;
      word = "";
    }
  }else
    word += str[i];
}
  if(passage.find(word) == passage.end())
      passage.insert(make_pair(word, 1));
    else
      passage[word]++;
    for(auto& it : passage) {
      cout << it.first << " - " << it.second << endl;                               
    }
}
```

output would be something like:

thisword - 2

thatword -3

anotherword - 1

etc..

Answer (score 1):

```
void wordCounter(string str, string wordsArray[], int countArray[]) {
  string word = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
    if (str[i] == ' ') {
      bool found = false;
      int spot = 0;
      int finder = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < wordsArray.length; j++) {
        String wd = wordsArray[j];
        if (wd == word) {
          spot = finder;
          found = true;
          break;
        }
        finder++;
      }
      if (found) {
        countArray[spot] = countArray[spot] + 1;
      } else {
        // wordsArray[spot + 1] = word
        // countArray[spot + 1] = 1
      }
      word = "";
    } else
      word += str[i];
  }

  // to print
  // loop through wordsArray and countArray simulatenously
  // do something like
  for (int simul = 0, simul  < wordsArray.length, simul++) {
    printf("%s %s\n", wordsArray[simul], countArray[simul]);
  }
}
```

Haven't used C++ in a little bit but essentially if you can't find the word in the arrays, you will want to append the new word to the end of the array and append 1 to the end of the countArray.

Comment: Okay I see what you did there mostly but I am not sure what the for(String wd : wordsArray) does exactly? what does wd stand for?